# Why does UVA penetrate deeper than UVB, though it's weaker?

Tags: biophysics, skin, radiation, uv

Even though UVA radiation [ranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet#Subtypes) in longer wavelengths (315–400 nm) than UVB (280–315 nm) and thus is less energetic, [UVA is able to penetrate deeper into the skin and even reach the dermis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2671032/). Why is there such a discrepancy?

Comment: Melanin itself may absorb more UVB? I speculate...

Comment: It's not simply a matter of energy, otherwise we wouldn't see different colors of transparent materials.  Different molecules &c preferrentially absorb different wavelenghts.  Probably there's nothing in the skin that absorbs UVA, just as lighter-skinned people don't have much that absorbs visible light.

Comment: This answer may be pertinent: [Interaction of radiation with the body](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/710626/8446).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our skin contains quite a lot of water and I think this is answers the question: The absorption of UV light by this water goes drastically up when you shift to shorter wavelengts with a minimum absorption in the UV-A spectrum. 
See this figure (from [here](http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/water_vibrational_spectrum.html#uv)):

[image]

So water has a very low absorption around 340-350nm (UV-A) and a very high absorption at shorter wavelength (UV-B and UV-C). This also explains why we get a lot more UV-A through the atmosphere than for harder UV-Radiation.